# Invalid URL scheme name "http-remoting" occurring when running application jar

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, jndi

I am using one of the JBoss JMS quickstart projects (HelloWorld-JMS) which uses JMS to write to a message queue. The queue has been defined in the JBoss XML configuration file. Our application runs perfectly fine when we run it from the IDE. However, when we package it as a JAR, we start seeing the exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception NamingException: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: WFNAM00007: Invalid URL scheme name "http-remoting"
```

We have also tried:

```
http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080
remoting+http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

But we get the same exception.

Here's the main part of my code:

```java
private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Hello, World!";
private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
private static final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "jms/queue/myqueue";
private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT = "1";
private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "john";
private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "doe";
private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory";
private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080";
Context namingContext = null;

String userName = System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME);
String password = System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

// Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

// Perform the JNDI lookups
String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
log.info("Attempting to acquire connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\"");
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);
log.info("Found connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\" in JNDI");
```

The exception occurs at this line:

```java
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);
```

These are the dependencies in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
   <version>7.3.4.GA</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
   <version>7.3.4.GA</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Final-redhat-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-ejb-client</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.37.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.wildfly.common</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-common</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.remotingjmx</groupId>
   <artifactId>remoting-jmx</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sorry for reaching out late. It didn't work.

Comment: Do you have any other solution in mind, which I should try?

Comment: So the *only* dependency you had in your `pom.xml` was `org.jboss.eap:wildfly-jms-client-bom` and you still got the same exception? If so, I'm not sure why this would work for the HelloWorld-JMS project and not yours. You probably want to add an update to your question detailing what you've tried.

Comment: the issue is not with the application. The application is running perfectly fine from the IDE. The exception only occurs when I package it in a jar and try to run it. I have mentioned this in my question too. You are right that the only dependency was what you mentioned. Yet, I still see the same exception when running it as a jar. As an application (exe), it runs perfectly fine and correctly does what it has to

Comment: How can you say, "the issue is not with the application," when you get an exception when you package the application in a jar and try to run it? How are you packaging and running the application when you see the exception? What is on the application's classpath? How are you packaging and running it as an "exe"?

Comment: problem was rightly in the classpath, it was not pointing to the correct classpaths.

P.S: sorry I mistakenly wrote exe for running an application through the ide.

Comment: OK. I assumed your application's classpath was being built from the Maven dependency list. I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes, it was, and thank you very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your classpath has overlapping classes on it. I see the same thing in your `pom.xml`. This will cause the wrong classes to be loaded at runtime.

For example, if you look at the [`pom.xml` of the HelloWorld-JMS](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/helloworld-jms/pom.xml#L51) project you'll see that it *only* uses the `wildfly-jms-client-bom`. In fact, the whole point of such a "bom" (i.e. bill of materials) is to incorporate *all* the required dependencies into a single dependency. Therefore, I recommend you just use this in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
   <version>7.3.4.GA</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Likewise, on your application's classpath you should only have the dependencies of `wildfly-jms-client-bom` on your classpath (or aggregated equivalents).